# call octave sort inside c++ dynamically linked function?

Tags: c++, octave

How does one sort an array in a written dynamically linked function for Octave written c++?

A hypothesized example :

```
#include <octaveoct.h>
#include <octave_sort_file?.h>
DEFUN_DLD (func_mysort, args, ,"sort an array")
  {
    octave_value o0_retval;
    Columnvector v1_vector = args(0).vector_value() ;
    octave_sort(v1_vector) ;
    o0_retval = v1_vector ;
    return o0_retval ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually easier that it seems, you only have to use the `sort()` method. Take a look at Octave's doxygen documentation for [`ColumnVector`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d0/d25/classColumnVector.html):

```
#include <octave/oct.h>

DEFUN_DLD (foo, args, , "sort an array")
{
  ColumnVector unsorted = args(0).vector_value ();
  ColumnVector sorted = unsorted.sort ();
  return octave_value (sorted);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the page that includes all kinds of good stuff. http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/annotated.html I assume that all classes listed in this link are provided in the <octave/oct.h> ?

Comment: @linuxfreebird No. not all. Some classes will still need specific includes but `octave/oct.h` will already load most of the stuff you need. I tend to start at [octave_value](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d3/d35/classoctave__value.html) and follow from there.

Comment: I fixed the fortran issue so no worries. I have an extended question related to octave sorting posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622335/how-to-row-sort-octave-matrices-using-sort-rows-from-oct-sort-h . Feel free to provide your expertise. Thank you for your time and consideration.